# How can I install my Lexmark Z25 printer?

Tags: drivers, printing

How or where I can get a driver for the Lexmark Z25-, to install on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS? ?

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.lexmark.com/publications/pdfs/z25-z35/eng/enoglinx.pdf:

**Printing from a software application**

1. From the File menu, choose Print. The Print dialog box opens.
2. Select your printer from the list of installed printers.
   If the software application does not offer a list of printers, but provides a place to enter your printer name, type: `lpr -Plexmarkz25-z35`.
3. Click Enter.